# Add padding to body but not to footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

Basically I am using bootstrap 4 and I have created a `body`, this `body` I wish to use `padding` left and right `20px` so I did this in the css file, however, when I create a `footer` I don't want this `padding` to apply, however, it applies only on the left side of the `footer`. Here is the footer code and the css code for `body` and `footer`.

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: white;
}

body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

[image]

Comment: The image link is the problem that is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't apply the padding to the body, create a wrapper for the body content and apply it to that instead.

```css
.body-content {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.footer {
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-content">
  Body content goes here
</div>
<footer class="footer">
<div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This worked perfectly. Is this bad practice though? Just putting things in wrappers?

Comment: No, it's actually good practice. I never put padding on `html` or `body` elements. In fact, I usually use a CSS reset to zero out the default margin/padding that the browser applies.

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't mentioned the `left` position of fixed `.footer`, so it is taking `left:auto` by default...

...so apply `left:0` to your `.footer`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #343a40;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
}

body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
  </div>
</footer>
```